# How to iterate and extract single objects from an array of objects to create a list

Tags: reactjs

I'm retrieving data from a list of businesses with one or multiple locations. From these locations I'm trying to feed useSupercluster with the list of all locations to display the markers on google map.

```
{
"count": 3,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "2 locations",
        "absolute_url": "/2-locations/",
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/uploads/IMG_0025_zNIdvu2.jpg",
        "locations": [
            {
                "pk": 4,
                "Address": "Petržalka, Slovakia",
                "latitude": "48.1108126915612",
                "longitude": "17.111585515344235",
                "hello": "hello"
            },
            {
                "pk": 5,
                "Address": "Ružinov, Slovakia",
                "latitude": "48.1575967",
                "longitude": "17.162797799999986",
                "hello": "hello"
            }
        ],
        "latitude": "48.1591643",
        "longitude": "17.05184429999999",
        "addressGmap": "Karlova Ves, Slovakia"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "test 2",
        "absolute_url": "/test-2/",
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/uploads/IMG_0020_sHsf4S8.jpg",
        "locations": [
            {
                "pk": 2,
                "Address": "Svätý Jur, Slovakia",
                "latitude": "48.25433740000002",
                "longitude": "17.21190739999998",
                "hello": "hello"
            }
        ],
        "latitude": "48.2502",
        "longitude": "17.2",
        "addressGmap": "Svätý Jur, Slovakia"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Flo Bratislava",
        "absolute_url": "/flo-bratislava/",
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/uploads/airplane-gdfcad3235_1280_rySWbtC.png",
        "locations": [
            {
                "pk": 1,
                "Address": "Bratislava-Hrad, Slovakia",
                "latitude": "48.144833000000006",
                "longitude": "17.10037926931151",
                "hello": "hello"
            }
        ],
        "latitude": "48.3006",
        "longitude": "17.11",
        "addressGmap": "Bratislava-Hrad, Slovakia"
    }
]}
```

The only way I know to access the data is to loop inside my loop, but this return 3 arrays with array (in case of multiple locations)

```
  const points = activities.map(activity => (
activity.locations.map(location => (

    {
        type: "Feature",
        properties: {
            cluster: false,
            id: activity.pk,
            business: activity.name

        },
        geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [activity.longitude,activity.latitude]}} 
),
)
```

What would me the right method to return "points" as a list?

Comment: use `flat()` method on `points`.

Comment: so simple, yes that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Or replace `map` by `flatMap` on `activities`.